# Decorated permutations and subset permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, grassmannians, total-positivity

**Decorated permutations** are defined as permutations where the fix-points come in two colors (say $\overline{\cdot}$ and $\underline{\cdot}$). For example, the 16 decorated permutations of length 3 are
$$\overline{1}\overline{2}\overline{3},\underline{1}\overline{2}\overline{3},\overline{1}\underline{2}\overline{3},\overline{1}\overline{2}\underline{3},\underline{1}\underline{2}\overline{3},\underline{1}\overline{2}\underline{3},\overline{1}\underline{2}\underline{3},\underline{1}\underline{2}\underline{3},$$
$$\overline{1}32,\underline{1}32,\hspace{10pt}
21\overline{3},21\underline{3},\hspace{10pt}
231,\hspace{10pt}
312,\hspace{10pt}
3\overline{2}1,3\underline{2}1\ .$$
They play an important role in the context of the positive Grassmannian and are in bijection with many other combinatorial objects such as **bounded affine permutations**, **Grassmann necklaces**, **Le-diagrams**, **positroids** and equivalence classes of **plabic graphcs**, see, for example, [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.00603) or [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609764). These combinatorial objects have certainly been studied in detail in recent years.
Their total number of clearly $\sum_{k=0}^n F(n,k)2^k$, where $F(n,k)$ denotes the number of permutations of length $n$ with $k$ fixed-points.

When looking for these on the [OEIS](http://www.oeis.org), I saw that *neither of the above names was found* there, whilst **subset permutations** are found there as [A000522](http://oeis.org/A000522). These are, given a set with $n$ elements, obtained by choosing $k$ elements among them, and then permute these $k$ elements, giving in total $\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n \choose k}k! = \sum_{k=0}^{n} n!/k!\ $.
For example, for $n=3$, we obtain the following 16 elements:
$$-,1,2,3,12,21,13,31,23,32,123,132,213,231,312,321.$$

I claim (and quickly prove below) that subset permutations also belong to the list of combinatorial objects in bijection with the above.

My questions are now

> Have the later already appeared in this context?

and

> Is the equality $\sum_{k=0}^n F(n,k)2^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n} n!/k!$ otherwise directly implied?

**Construction of the bijection**:

Take a subset permutation. This is, take a set of $k$ element in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ together with a permutation of these.
Consider this as a permutation of length $n$ with the remaining $n-k$ elements being fixed-points.
Now label these $n-k$ fixed-points by $\underline{\cdot}$ and the additional fixed-points from the permutation of the $k$ elements by $\overline{\cdot}$.
Than this is a bijection from subset permutations to decorated permutations.

For example, $143768$ as a subset permutation of $\{1,\ldots,8\}$ is mapped to $\overline{1}\underline{2}43\underline{5}76\overline{8}$.
Also, the preimages of the 16 decorated permutations at the beginning are
$$123,23,13,12,3,2,1,-,132,32,213,21,231,312,321,31.$$

Answer (score 5):

Here is a direct proof for the formula via generating functions.

Using the formula for [derrangement numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), we have $$\begin{split}
F(n,k)=&\binom nk\cdot !(n-k)\\
=&\frac{n!}{k!}\cdot [x^{n-k}]\ \frac{e^{-x}}{1-x},
\end{split}$$
where $[x^d]$ is the operator of taking the coefficient of $x^d$.

Then
$$\begin{split}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} F(n,k)\cdot 2^k = & \sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^k\frac{n!}{k!} [x^{n-k}]\ \frac{e^{-x}}{1-x} \\
=  & n!\sum_{k=0}^{n} [x^k]\ e^{2x}\cdot [x^{n-k}]\ \frac{e^{-x}}{1-x} \\
= & n!\cdot [x^n]\ \frac{e^{x}}{1-x}\\
= &\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!}.
\end{split}$$

Answer (score 3):

Max's answer is neat in using $e^{2x}\frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}=\frac{e^x}{1-x}$. We offer one approach without generating functions. To this end, let $f_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}$ and $g_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{2^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}$. Assume empty sums to be $0$. Clearly, $f_{n+1}-f_n=\frac1{(n+1)!}$. On the other hand, we have
\begin{align} g_{n+1}-g_n
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{2^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{n+1-k}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}
-\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{2^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{2^k}{k!}\frac{(-1)^{n+1-k}}{(n+1-k)!}
=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}k(-2)^k \\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}(-1)^{n+1}=\frac1{(n+1)!}.
\end{align}
Therefore, $f_{n+1}-f_n=g_{n+1}-g_n$. Since $f_0=g_0=1$, it follows $f_n=g_n$ and $n!f_n=n!g_n$. Obviously, $n!f_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!}$ and
$$n!g_n=\sum_{k=0}^n2^k\frac{n!}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}=\sum_{k=0}^n2^k\binom{n}k\cdot !(n-k)=\sum_{k=0}^nF(n,k)2^k.$$